# Flutter - No file or variants found for asset: lib/assets/images

Tags: flutter, dart, assets

I'm getting this error while adding images folder assets in `pubspec.yaml`

```
Error detected in pubspec.yaml:
No file or variants found for asset: lib/assets/images.
```

This is how my `pubspec.yaml` file looks like

```
flutter:
  uses-material-design: true
  
  assets:
    - lib/assets/images
  
  fonts:
    - family: Potra
      fonts:
        - asset: lib/assets/fonts/Potra.ttf
    - family: BAHNSCHRIFT
      fonts:
        - asset: lib/assets/fonts/BAHNSCHRIFT.TTF
```

I tried to look it up. Most of the people are suggesting to give the right indentation for this problem. But I'm quite sure it is not the case here. I tried the proper indentation method and also all possible variants but in vain.

When I remove below part, code runs fine without any error and respective added font family in pubspec also works fine.

```
  assets:
    - lib/assets/images
```

Why I'm getting error after adding assets part?

This is how my file structure looks like

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your code doesn't work because you need to add one more slash, so it should be like:

```
  assets:
    - lib/assets/images/
```

**Tips:** It's kinda bad practice if you put your `assets` folder inside your `lib` folder. Try to place it outside the `lib` folder. And also make sure the indentations are correct.

I hope it will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I got this exception for a silly mistake I have space in my file name like `home_cover. jpg`. So I remove it like `home_cover.jpg`

Answer (score -1):

You should have your assets folder not inside lib folder but in the main root directory( i.e. out of lib ) and then add assets as :

```
assets:
    # For images
    - assets/images
fonts:
    - family: FontFamilyName     
        fonts:
            - asset: assets/fonts/the_font_you_want.ttf
```

And beware of indentation in pubspec.yaml, they also cause errors

Comment: It has to be - assets/images/ with trailing slash for directories.